# <li> won't show bullet points in google chrome using html

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-lists

As I mentioned in my title, I'm practicing some basic html on an old laptop (lenovo x250) with sublime text 3 and when I save and refresh chrome, i see one bullet point far from the 3  I have on there.

Here's the code and thanks in advance!

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>index</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>My Page</h1>
                <hr>
                <h3>About Me</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <hr>
                <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
                <li>
                    <ol>Basketball</ol>
                    <ol>Basketball</ol>
                    <ol>Basketball</ol>
                </li>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct format is

```
<ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>index</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>My Page</h1>
                <hr>
                <h3>About Me</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <hr>
                <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
                <ol>
                    <li>Basketball</li>
                    <li>Basketball</li>
                    <li>Basketball</li>
                </ol>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html ordering format is wrong:

Ordered List:

```
<ol>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3</li>
</ol>
```

Unordered List:

```
<ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3</li>
</ul>
```

This is a very basic of HTML. I suggest you to do some research before posting.